# How to send ArrayList send an other class

Tags: java, class, arraylist, send

How can I send an ArrayList  from one class to another in java?
I want to send a variable in a form of a object from one class to another. I tried several ways such as final static but I failed.
Do you have any solution?

```
public class  A(){
 private int a1,a2;
 public geta1(int a1);
 public geta2(int a2);
 public seta1(int a1);
 public seta2(int a2);}

public class class1(){
A =new A();
A.seta1(5);
//....................}

public class class2(){
//}
```

How I can build an object in class one and a1=5 in a way that this object could be available in class 2 too with this amount.

Comment: where is the ArrayList in the code ??

Comment: Hint: read a little bit about java coding styleguides. Class names start with upper case. And please understand: this is really basic stuff. This would be normally something you simply **learn** by studying books/tutorials. And of course, it has been asked here zillion times before. So please do **prior research** the next time.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the ArrayList in class1 and create a getter method that returns it.
e.g.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class class1 {
    private ArrayList<Integer> myList;
    public ArrayList<Integer> getList() {
        return myList;
    }
    //..other methods of the class
}
```

And then:

```
class1 object = new class1();
ArrayList<Integer> myList = object.getList();
```

You could also make it static (part of the class, rather than a part of an instance of the class) if that's what you need

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class class1 {
    private static ArrayList<Integer> myList;
    public static ArrayList<Integer> getList() {
        return myList;
    }
    //..other methods of the class
}
```

and then just call

```
ArrayList<Integer> myList = class1.getList();
```